# C++ Windows Minimize Not Registered

Tags: c++, windows

I have added minimize & restore cases to my even processing, but I found out they are never hit.

Only on startup of the program does **Size_Minimized** get hit. Afterwards, minimize case never happens.
The **Size_Restore** case never happens either.

**Debug stopping at Size_Minimize only on startup of program:**
[image]

My other cases work, so I have no idea why minimize & restore dont trigger my code or break points.
I conclude that **Size_Minimized** & **Size_Restore** are not related to what I need.

*What is it I need to know to handle minimize/restore?*

Code, in case I did it wrong:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;



    switch(message){
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;

    case SIZE_MINIMIZED:
        break;

    case SIZE_RESTORED:
        break;

    case WM_SIZING:
    case WM_SIZE:
        if(engine.isReady()) engine.resizeDevice();
        if(engine.isReady()) engine.draw();
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would imagine it's available through the `wParam` of `WM_SIZE`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SIZE_MINIMIZED` and `SIZE_RESTORED` are constants passed to you through the `WM_SIZE` message; they are not window messages. Your breakpoint is getting hit whenever your window receives a window message with the same id as `SIZE_MINIMIZED` and/or `SIZE_RESTORED`.

You would need to have your code look something like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    switch(message){
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;


    case WM_SIZE:
        switch(wParam) {
        case SIZE_MINIMIZED:
          // Do whatever
          break;
        case SIZE_RESTORED:
          // Do whatever
          break;
        }
    case WM_SIZING:
        if(engine.isReady()) engine.resizeDevice();
        if(engine.isReady()) engine.draw();
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't even notice that they were those same constants :p I can tell you `SIZE_MINIMIZED` shares the same value as `WM_CREATE`, and `SIZE_RESTORED` is 0, which is `WM_NULL`.

Comment: O wait, so I dont switch on size_minimize/restore using UINT message? Let me fix that & come back.